# Docker in Windows Server 2016 is not working

Tags: docker, containers, windows-server-2016

I have a new Windows Server 2016, with all updates applied.

I followed the commands from the [quick-start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-server) and all of them went fine.

Now when I run the command to Pull the image and run I got this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run microsoft/dotnet-samples:dotnetapp-nanoserver
Unable to find image 'microsoft/dotnet-samples:dotnetapp-nanoserver' locally
dotnetapp-nanoserver: Pulling from microsoft/dotnet-samples
bce2fbc256ea: Pull complete
6330793656b1: Pull complete
8f8cb03e6bbd: Pull complete
b9af2c542781: Pull complete
6678bd54d501: Pull complete
599687f54f31: Pull complete
76bce04be051: Pull complete
cba1545990b9: Pull complete
5133eeec3675: Pull complete
fc46a60df016: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:eedf7f663ab010f2e0d91a875494cb074e9f24372e77fa12bc1b1842cb1350ed
Status: Downloaded newer image for microsoft/dotnet-samples:dotnetapp-nanoserver
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container 0ec42882ada176282ba457f71b80176d81d02380e66f04
5ab6462a9facd2ee1b encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find
 the path specified. (0x3) extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"0ec42882ada176282ba457f71b80176d81d02380e66f045
ab6462a9facd2ee1b","Owner":"docker","IsDummy":false,"VolumePath":"\\\\?\\Volume{56859652-5d7a-11e7-9118-001dd8b721db}","
IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\0ec42882ada176282ba457f71b80176
d81d02380e66f045ab6462a9facd2ee1b","Layers":[{"ID":"ea083094-a611-5c12-84fd-7f9aa15d2b35","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docke
r\\windowsfilter\\f180b23b936645af2fa5be06079d2901c47d0debf54aaa5f3b1f36776f87417d"},{"ID":"4789ef77-4eb2-59b3-987e-91a7
6bbd1ad2","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\a614557d0370cf0181261fe2432a42a5b0bc0c50ad86e801e88d68388ff899
82"},{"ID":"4cce79bb-2bbc-5b1d-97f1-3f4ef57af815","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\a5f22e5e987874f5d252ba
83b4115c0ae0501d4b20f3bf859798dd191f513869"},{"ID":"06079bb2-e3b1-58a0-bc47-551bf70ccdc9","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docke
r\\windowsfilter\\9707026fac7a1c2124c36e8cb2e50194842674938b072171206f558f9cf1b6a9"},{"ID":"a3ff8716-0b40-5db6-83d7-9d9b
0930baa5","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\d8c5963bf90b6529392ef8606b4c6d1a1c4e49faf1df9cea5c495f049a2c03
f8"},{"ID":"6014c41c-dd4a-54e7-b564-8d9b53acbe0d","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\4e0e1976378d8cc7dc8f90
1acbfc49ef05f570ac0254e3fb50ded39c814caf8c"},{"ID":"bc06dd52-c4cb-5d81-b40c-adecbd934138","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docke
r\\windowsfilter\\4148580680a3738a9ed7a669e52edd7daa99a7432d185ad2259191ade608c32e"},{"ID":"78e01f7d-74d9-5aff-ac9a-fc91
453fec11","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\0f16555a7ded5a750bc57edfc5d269f16c42f8d939c943fee20811e48cd6bd
8b"},{"ID":"4d477170-a3ac-503a-84f1-28659c65f0ba","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\20bba5241594bea7627edf
69a78ba17934e9ca0df47496d1293633cd9380bf01"},{"ID":"e63caf38-f16c-5dbc-9c92-0be7525feb8c","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docke
r\\windowsfilter\\3f3093891e2d0ada91701fd1b170f54df4aa02546ba5c40763d2c0af4acf050c"}],"HostName":"0ec42882ada1","MappedD
irectories":[],"HvPartition":false,"EndpointList":["a0f8f1be-f0b2-467f-8f75-141e28364639"],"Servicing":false,"AllowUnqua
lifiedDNSQuery":true}.
```

Seems that something is missing in my server, but no clue what it could be. Someone had similar experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have SEP 14 MP1 by default in my servers. **Once I removed it, docker worked**.

I tried to simply disable it, but still, SEP blocks somehow.

Comment: What is "SEP 14 MP1", and where/how did you remove it :)

Comment: Might be Symantec Endpoint Protection 14 MP1 https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.ALERT2206.html