# Container xxx encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Why will all my containers not start? Everytime I get the following error:

```
PS C:\temp> docker run hello-world:nanoserver
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container cec0e5f7f4036b1131a0bac64fd4584b1a5a4e281c328e
1469b552d2a71a573d encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find
 the file specified. (0x2) extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"cec0e5f7f4036b1131a0bac64fd4584b1a5a4e281c328e1
469b552d2a71a573d","Owner":"docker","IsDummy":false,"VolumePath":"\\\\?\\Volume{ab8f2c3c-c60e-11e8-a954-000d3a29ddea}","
IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\cec0e5f7f4036b1131a0bac64fd4584
b1a5a4e281c328e1469b552d2a71a573d","Layers":[{"ID":"c16957a2-b267-5d69-bed2-b88101cfd068","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docke
r\\windowsfilter\\dd06f430510c44d8de638de561e2dc03f0767f5c25f7de473afbd4fecdd2966a"},{"ID":"022a60a1-3ff0-53ed-834c-d94c
20ace7d3","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\143b5173dbffea4cff3a50c45deea80304965912ae12cade49148c5fa5896e
a6"},{"ID":"33227722-bcc0-563e-9aea-d65ad26f3975","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\7c2ea9d76aaf65f480b6af
c5360a1e94a82bdad25a94ff4e3d3dd10ce66d3b83"},{"ID":"3c04557d-f902-5ce7-baaf-103387e002f8","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docke
r\\windowsfilter\\a573e37ad3ec7dfe2ad94311e2f1a4315f3632bde004a4e1444640b9e993126a"}],"HostName":"cec0e5f7f403","MappedD
irectories":[],"HvPartition":false,"EndpointList":["70b4a434-9bea-4631-a67c-f5ed8667edb9"],"Servicing":false,"AllowUnqua
lifiedDNSQuery":true}.
```

I have installed Docker Enterprise for Windows as described here: https://docs.docker.com/install/windows/docker-ee/:

```
Install-Module DockerMsftProvider -Force
Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
Restart-Computer
```

and run the container with:

```
docker run hello-world:nanoserver
```

The container starts as expected the first time, but the second and following times it fails with the same error.

I suspect that it is network related. Because if I run the daemon with the -b "None" parameter then it works:

```
dockerd.exe -b "none"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
PS C:\temp> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ee-16
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.7
 Git commit:   9ef4f0a
 Built:        Thu Jul 26 16:43:19 2018
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.06.2-ee-16
  API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:   go1.8.7
  Git commit:   9ef4f0a
  Built:        Thu Jul 26 16:52:17 2018
  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44889113/1244816) we found it was the anti virus that caused the issue.
Like the post mentions, **removing** (not just disabling) the anti virus fixed the problem. 


Excally what about the anti virus that didn't work with docker, remains to be seen.

Comment: Yes, Trend Micro. It seems to be enough to exclude the folder c:/programdata/docker. But we still verifying.